# Error while running rails on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to set my machine up so I can follow this tutorial:  [the intro to rails screen-cast i wish i had](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had).

I keep running into issues, most recently the following:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ansi-1.4.1/lib/ansi/code.rb:5:in `require':
no such file to load -- Win32/Console/ANSI (LoadError)
```

This occurs when ever I run `rails g`. (I would like to see if my r spec generator has been added.)

Environment details:  Windows 7, ruby 1.9.2p290, rails 3.1.1, rubygems 1.8.15

Comment: in my terminal i entered "gem install win32console". I now have the following directory on my system: C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32  But i guess, this isn't what rails is looking for. I ge the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you installed "gem install win32console", can you add this gem into your Gemfile file and try to run bundle install again?

**Gemfile**

```
gem "win32console", "~> 1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

[RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) may be your best bet if you're looking for an integrated Windows Rails experience.

It's up-to-date *(-ish, doesn't use Ruby 1.9.3)* with:

- Ruby 1.9.2-p290
- Rails 3.1.1
- Git 1.7.6

and other useful bits.